# Minecraft nether portal info

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been playing Minecraft for a little over a year now and I finally got a portal to the Nether. I've been in the Nether for a while, but now I'm lost and trying to find my way back before I starve, so I've pretty much used up my resources.

So my question is: if I break my portal (in the overworld) and then fix and relight it, will the corresponding portal in the Nether spawn in the same spot, or somewhere else?

Comment: As you can see in @Judge2020 reaction, to much backstory can hurt the understanding of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nether portal mechanics: what happens if I destroy the overworld portal?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/257685/nether-portal-mechanics-what-happens-if-i-destroy-the-overworld-portal)

Answer (score 0):

If you are really lost, you can put all of your stuff in a chest, note the coordinates, then jump into the lava and die. Dying will transport you to your respawn point. Then, if you really want to get your stuff back, you can come back to the nether when you are not lost and grab your stuff from the chest.

Answer (score 0):

The portal will still be in the same spot

Answer (score 0):

The portal will be in the same spot. What I recommend doing is to find a bastion or a ruined portal where you can find obsidian which can hopefully make you a nether portal to get you back to the overworld. If you get the subspace bubble acheivement, you have travelled more than 875 nether blocks (7000 overworld blocks) and you are probably screwed. If you don't get the achievement, you know you are close to your original portal.

NB. It is recommended you take down your coordinates for your base and nether portal.

Answer (score -1):

It will just teleport you to the existing portal in the nether. If you break that portal,and fix the one in the overworld. It will create another portal 5-ish (not an official statement) blocks away from the other one.

So. If you want another spawn in the nether,just make an overworld portal 100-ish blocks away from the current one.

Comment: By "100-ish blocks away" Kezeroth means "around a kilometer away". A portal looks for a matching portal within 128 blocks horizontally *in the target dimension*, and 128 meters in the Nether are 1024 meters in the Overworld.