# Nether portal mechanics: what happens if I destroy the overworld portal?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

**tldr; What happens to the nether-portal in the nether, if you destroy the portal in the overworld?** Will the portal in the nether disappear? Or will taking it spawn a new random portal in the overworld?

...

I recently started playing Minecraft again after a long hiatus, on an extremely hostile server making survival very difficult.

In order to survive, one must utilize the nether to get far enough away from spawn, in order to find trees, grass, animals, etc.

My buddy and I are semi-established, yes still relatively close to spawn, so in constant danger of being raided. Especially considering how we followed a pre-made nether-highway to get to where we are, others could get here too.

Now, we should probably relocate even further away from spawn, probably diagonally via. our own nether-pathway and create our own portal to ensure our safety, however I do not know much about the mechanics of the nether portal and am wondering: What happens to the nether-portal in the nether, if you destroy the portal in the overworld?

Bonus question: Baked potatoes vs. Bread?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade Paul! I prefer [PotatOS](http://orig02.deviantart.net/9bdb/f/2012/319/c/0/glados_potato_by_transparentstuff-d5l4fps.png) myself. [NBN-Alex](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/28029143#28029143) knows the answer it was in Alpha 5, I'll check in 1.9 in a sec.

Comment: Short answer: nothing.

Comment: I gotta test it since the last time I tried this was in Beta 2 (?) with multiplayer.  Overall though: If an exit port is destoried, then a new exit will be created.  With that said, destorying the Overworld portal will leave the underworld one intact, but the "exit" of the underworld portal can and usually appears somewhere else close in the world.  (The math is different between when a chunk needs to be created, and if one exist already.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't affect the one in the Nether. Really when you reconstruct it again you teleport to the same place where you have an automatic portal. Same thing when you destroy the portal in the Nether and reconstruct it.

Answer (score 3):

Nether portals do not have any long-term association with each other (there is a short-term destination cache). Destroying a portal will not affect any other portals.

When a player or entity passes through a nether portal minecraft will calculate the corresponding coordinates in the other dimension. It will then search around those coordinates for a nether portal. If it finds one the player or entity will be teleported there.

If a player passes through a nether portal and an appropriate destination portal cannot be found a location will be chosen near the calculated destination coordinates and a new portal will be generated. This is unlikely* to be in the same location as the portal you destroyed. I'm not sure if this also works for entities or not.

Many players prefer to build both nether portals by hand to get more control over their size and location.

* Unless the original portal was itself an automatically generated one *and* you thouroughly destroyed it.

Comment: This *will* not be the same coordinates as the destroyed portal, unless it has been thoroughly cleared. First, the new overworld portal will try to match the Nether coords better - the Nether side portal likely spawned a little off, forced to move due to terrain constraints, and with the 8x multiplier the "little off" in Nether turns to "quite a distance" in the overworld. And then, if the newly spawned OW portal is damaged too, its remains constitute a terrain obstacle forcing another new portal to spawn in such a position it doesn't collide with the old, broken one.